Better approach to 'pivot' the data of a table
I have a table with below structure:
create table test_table
(queuename    number,
 duration_sum number,
 rating_sum   number,
 rating_avg   number,
 rating_cnt   number
 )

Here is the sample data:
insert into test_table (queuename, duration_sum, rating_sum, rating_avg,rating_cnt)
values (1000,50,40,60,70);
insert into test_table (queuename, duration_sum, rating_sum, rating_avg,rating_cnt)
values (1010,12,40,25,34);
insert into test_table (queuename, duration_sum, rating_sum, rating_avg,rating_cnt)
values (2000,50,34,60,23);
insert into test_table (queuename, duration_sum, rating_sum, rating_avg,rating_cnt)
values (3000,90,40,60,67);
commit;

What I need is below result:
 queuename         1000     1010     2000     3000     
 duration_sum       50       12       50       90 
 rating_sum         40       40       34       40 
 rating_avg         60       25       60       60  
 rating_cnt         70       34       23       67 

Im trying to use pivot for this and this is what I have written so far:
select *
from (
    select 
        queuename,
        'duration_sum' as measure, duration_sum as value from test_table
    union all
    select 
        queuename,
        'rating_sum' as measure, rating_sum as value from test_table
    union all
    select 
        queuename,
        'rating_avg' as measure, rating_avg as value from test_table
    union all
    select 
        queuename,
        'rating_cnt' as measure, rating_cnt as value from test_table
         )
pivot (
    max(value)
    for queuename in (1000 as "1000", 1010 as "1010", 2000 as "2000", 3000 as "3000")
       )
order by measure;

I this a better approach for pivoting the result? I guess there might be a better approach for using pivot statement rather than using union. I should say that 'queuename' is unique.
Thanks in advance.

Your data is already pivoted but not by the columns you need. You can unpivot then pivot again:
select * from
( 
  select * from test_table 
  unpivot (value for measure in 
    ( 
      duration_sum as 'duration_sum', rating_sum as 'rating_sum', 
      rating_avg as 'rating_avg', rating_cnt as 'rating_cnt'
    )
  )
)
pivot
(
  max(value) for queuename in
    (
      1000 as "1000", 1010 as "1010", 2000 as "2000", 3000 as "3000"
    )
)    
order by measure;

MEASURE            1000       1010       2000       3000
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
duration_sum         50         12         50         90
rating_avg           60         25         60         60
rating_cnt           70         34         23         67
rating_sum           40         40         34         40

